# x264 rate control modes

Tags: h.264, x264

Recently I am reading the x264 source codes. Mostly, I concern the RC part. And I am confused about the parameters ***--bitrate*** and ***--vbv-maxrate***. When ***bitrate*** is set, the CBR mode is used in frame level. If you want to start the MB level RC, the parameters ***bitrate***, ***vbv-maxrate*** and ***vbv-bufsize*** should be set. But I don't know the relationship between ***bitrate*** and ***vbv-maxrate***. What is the criterion of the real encoding result when ***bitrate*** and ***vbv-maxrate*** are both set?
And what is the recommended value for ***bitrate***? Equals to ***vbv-maxrate***?
Also what is the recommended value for ***vbv-bufsize***? Half of ***vbv-maxrate***?
Please give me some advice.

Answer (score 0):

bitrate address the "target filesize" when you are doing encoding. It is understandably confusing because it applies a "budget" of certain size and then tries to apportion this budget on the frames - that is why the later parts of a movie get a smaller amount of data which results in lower video quality. For example, if you have 10 seconds of complete black images followed by 10 second of natural video - the final encoded file will be very different than if the order was the opposite.

vbv-bufsize is the buffer that has to be completed before a "transmission" would occur say in a streaming scenario. Now, let's tie this to I-frames and P-frames: the vbv-bufsize will limit the size of any of your encoded video frames - most likely the I-frame.