# How to validate properly ffmpeg pts/dts after demuxing/decoding?

Tags: c++, c, ffmpeg, libav

How should I validate pts/dts after demuxing and then after decoding?

For me it is significant to have valid pts all the time for days and
possibly weeks of continuous streaming.

After demuxing I check:

1. dts <= pts
2. prev_packet_dts < next_packet_pts
3. I also discard packets with AV_NOPTS_VALUE and wait for packets with
   proper pts, because I don't know video duration at this case.

- pts of packets can be not increasing because of I-P-B frames
  Is it all right?

What about decoded AVFrames?

1. Should 'pts' be increasing all the time?
2. Why at some point 'pts' could lag behind 'dts'?
3. Why pict_type is a parameter of AVFrame? Should be at AVPacket, because
   AVPacket is a compressed frame, not the opposite?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

At libav support I was advised to not rely on decoder output. It is more solid to produce pts/dts for encoding/muxing manually and I should search for ffmpeg tools sources to proper implementation. I will search for this approach.

For now I discard AVFrames only with AV_NOPTS_VALUE, and the rest of encoding/muxing works fine.

Validation of AVPackets after Demuxing remains the same, as described above.

Answer (score 1):

1. Ideally, yes. Unless if your format allows discontinuities, or wraps timestamps around due to overflow, like MPEG-TS.
2. Writing error.
3. It is an informational field, indicating the provenance of the frame. It can be used by filters or encoders, e.g. keyframe alignment during a re-encode.

Comment: 2. I don't record any errors during transcoding. But I was a bit wrong about AVFrame::pkt_dts, I thought it matters during encoding and appears it is not. For now I stopped validate decoder pts/dts and transcoding still valid.

Comment: *I thought it matters during encoding and appears it is not*  --> it does, for ratecontrol purposes. See https://stackoverflow.com/a/49623331/

Comment: there was nothing about pkt_dts specifically. Frame duration for encoding estimations could be get just from pts values. Doesn't it?